# AlertDialog not waiting for input

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm a volunteer with very limited Java/Android Studio experience. This UpdateView.java has two "toggle" buttons. When one of these buttons is first pressed, a status and datetime is saved for that participant. If pressed again, the same button allows clearing of these values (in case a mistake was made). I would like to insert a Y/N confirmation but only before clearing the values. I read a lot of posts on AlertDialog and tried my best to implement this. However, when I press the button a second time to clear, I can see briefly the Yes/No dialog but it doesn't wait for keypress and performs the clear immediately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.org.suivicourse2.View;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.org.suivicourse2.Base.BaseActivity;
import com.org.suivicourse2.Database.DBHelper;
import com.org.suivicourse2.Model.Coureurs;
import com.org.suivicourse2.R;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class UpdateView extends BaseActivity {
    ImageView back_btn;

    TextView dossard_view;
    TextView prenom_view;
    TextView nom_view;
    TextView sexe_view;
    TextView epreuve_view;
    TextView tempsPassage_view;
    TextView statut_view;

    LinearLayout exit_btn;
    LinearLayout dnf_btn;
    LinearLayout update_btn;

    Coureurs model;
    private DBHelper my_db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
        initView();
    }
    private void initView(){
        model = (Coureurs)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("model");

        back_btn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        dossard_view = findViewById(R.id.dossard);
        prenom_view = findViewById(R.id.Prenom);
        nom_view = findViewById(R.id.Nom);
        sexe_view = findViewById(R.id.Sexe);
        epreuve_view = findViewById(R.id.Epreuve);
        tempsPassage_view = findViewById(R.id.TempsPassage);
        statut_view = findViewById(R.id.Statut);

        exit_btn = findViewById(R.id.exit_btn);
        dnf_btn = findViewById(R.id.dnf_btn);
        update_btn = findViewById(R.id.update_btn);

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        exit_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        dnf_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        update_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        initValues();
    }
    private void initValues(){
        dossard_view.setText(String.valueOf(model.getDossard()));
        prenom_view.setText(model.getPrenom());
        nom_view.setText(model.getNom());
        sexe_view.setText(model.getSexe());
        epreuve_view.setText(model.getEpreuve());
        tempsPassage_view.setText(model.getTempsPassage());
        statut_view.setText(model.getStatut());
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        super.onClick(view);
        if(view == back_btn){
            finish();
        }else if(view == exit_btn){
            finish();
        }else if(view == dnf_btn){
            update_dnf();
        }else if(view == update_btn){
            update();
        }
    }
    // PYT Button TEMPS as a toggle - Set/Clear DateTime for this racer
    private void update(){
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat time_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String current_time = time_format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            String old_time = model.getTempsPassage();
            String statut = model.getStatut();
            if(statut.equals("En_Course")){
                if (old_time != null && !old_time.equals("")) {

                    // Added following code for Yes/No confirmation
                    
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    //Yes button clicked
                                    break;
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    //No button clicked
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
                    
                    // End of code added for Yes/No confirmation 
                    
                    my_db = new DBHelper(context);
                    my_db.updateCoureurs(model.getDossard(), null);
                    showMessage("Temps de passage EFFACÉ pour ce coureur");
                }else{
                    my_db = new DBHelper(context);
                    my_db.updateCoureurs(model.getDossard(), current_time);
                    //showMessage("Temps de passage assigné à ce coureur");
                }
            }
            finish();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            showMessage(getString(R.string.fail_update));
        }
    }
    // PYT Button DNF as a toggle - Set/Clear DNF and DateTime for this racer
    private void update_dnf(){
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat time_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String current_time = time_format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            String statut = model.getStatut();
            String new_statut;
            if(statut.equals("En_Course")){
                new_statut = "DNF";
                my_db = new DBHelper(context);
                my_db.dnfCoureurs(model.getDossard(), current_time, new_statut);
                showMessage("Statut DNS/DNF assigné à ce coureur");
            }else{
                new_statut = "En_Course";
                my_db = new DBHelper(context);
                my_db.dnfCoureurs(model.getDossard(), current_time, new_statut);
                showMessage("Statut En_Course ré-assigné à ce coureur");
            }
            finish();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            showMessage(getString(R.string.fail_update));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SteveHaley I was reading one of your old answers on this topic. I'm pretty sure my issue is about context but I just can't get it right.  Could you please have a look? Thank you so much. Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Those 3 lines need to go into the click listener of your yes/no dialog:

```
                    my_db = new DBHelper(context);
                    my_db.updateCoureurs(model.getDossard(), null);
                    showMessage("Temps de passage EFFACÉ pour ce coureur");
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander . Could you please be more specific? Everything i have tried so far displays the dialog box briefly but returns to the main activity before I can make a selection. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only editing the `update` function

```
private void update(){
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat time_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        String current_time = time_format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        String old_time = model.getTempsPassage();
        String statut = model.getStatut();
        if(statut.equals("En_Course")){
            if (old_time != null && !old_time.equals("")) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            my_db = new DBHelper(context);
                            my_db.updateCoureurs(model.getDossard(), null);
                            showMessage("Temps de passage EFFACÉ pour ce coureur");
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }).show();
            }else{
                my_db = new DBHelper(context);
                my_db.updateCoureurs(model.getDossard(), current_time);
                showMessage("Temps de passage assigné à ce coureur");
            }
        }
        finish();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        showMessage(getString(R.string.fail_update));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Aiman . I copied the update function you provided, except I used "new AlertDialog.Builder(context)". It briefly flashes the Yes/No prompt but still doesn't wait for a Y/N choice before returning to the main activity. What should I do next? Thanks again